# Why do I sporadically get SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED in python 2.7.9+?

Tags: ssl, python

Let me start off by saying that I am aware of Python 2.7.9's changes to verify SSL certificates. I'm also aware of a few different ways to hack around it to turn it off. My question is that why do I sporadically get this error? I would think, if something is wrong it would always consistently fail, but that is not what I am seeing. I've been working on some code all day that happens to be making some requests using `urllib` and just out of nowhere I started getting the following error:

`URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)>`

As I was writing this question, I stashed and popped my changes (in git) and the error stopped. Why the inconsistency?

UPDATE:
This error also happens in Python 3 but it happens consistently.

Comment: Are you connecting to different servers?

Comment: Every time I run the tests I'm connecting to the same servers... is that what you're asking?

Comment: So there are more than one of them, then?

Comment: Not for a given request... my code uses urllib to connect to different services, but each service is a single server.

Comment: Do you also get these failures on current Python (version 3)? Many things have been vastly improved, including the cert checking. Also I recomment using the requests package for non low-level usage.

Comment: @sebix unfortunately the application is not Python 3 compatible... yet

Comment: @MatthewJMorrison Port it. Support for Python 2 will end soon and it is highly encouraged to upgrade soon.

Comment: @sebix python 2.7 should not just be completely broken to the point that it cannot be used... I still want to know what the problem is or where to look next to try to figure out what is going on. I honestly have a hard time believing the problem lies with Python 2.7

Comment: is it not possible you have different virtual hosts on the server but the certificate is valid only for a few of them and by chance your code is contactng server with the wrong name?

Comment: It's a bit hard to answer this without seeing the code in question, but one possibility is the import path of urllib. The methods to disable ssl cert checking depend on applying a change to the module after it is imported. Thus try checking `id(<my_urllib_object>)` or `id(<urllib_object>.__module__)` at the points in your code where this occurs and compare it against somewhere that it doesn't. Perhaps one instance has checking disabled and another doesn't.

Comment: Have you used wireshark to inspect the handshake? Is it always the same?

Comment: @FrancescoMalvezzi That is not possible.

Comment: @AlexForbes I'm not disabling ssl cert checking at all.

Comment: @dfc I have not tried to use wireshark. The problem is very unpredictable, so it is hard to recreate consistently.

Comment: You just leave that running in the background and open up the pcap files when it misbehaves. There is little effort required so the sporadic nature should not be a big concern.

Answer (score 0):

I may have solved this issue. It turns out that my apache configuration was missing the `SSLCertificateChainFile` setting. I know for sure that this fixes the Python 3 error since it was happening consistently. I assume that it will no longer occur in Python 2.7.9 either, but do not have a way to recreate the error in Python 2 so I cannot know for sure.